# File handling in core java

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I need to do some housekeeping.I accidentally setup my classpath same as my codebase and all classes are placed along with my code.I need to write a quick java program to select all files of the type .class and .class alone and delete it immediately.Has anyone done something related to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the shell to do that, something like:

Linux:

```
 find . -name *.class -print -exec rm {} \;
```

Windows:

```
 for /r %f in (*.class) do del %f
```

Comment: make a backup first. Just in case.

Comment: I assume that I should run from the package where I should remove the .class files and it will go any levels deep.

Comment: This will look in sub-directory of the current one. And sure, backup is always a good idea

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.class" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work.  Untested.  Those find/for commands by the others look promising, too, but just in case you are on an OS/390 mainframe here is the Java.  ;-)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RemoveClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File(".");
        deleteRecursive(f);
    }

    public static void deleteRecursive(File f) throws IOException {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
                deleteRecursive(file);
            }
        } else if (f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".class")) {

            String path = f.getCanonicalPath();

            // f.delete();
            System.out.println("Uncomment line above to delete: [" + path + "]");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On OS/390 (assuming it's similar to AS/400), there is a `QSHELL` with `find` :)